# Ping spiking to 1000 in every game on Roblox with good internet

Tags: roblox

Alright, so before you say it's my internet, it's not. I can watch 4k videos without any buffering and every other application that needs a strong internet download speed runs perfectly fine. It's just Roblox, and I don't know what to do about it. Every 3 seconds my ping goes to 1k and stays like that for 10 seconds, and it just keeps doing that.

**Things I did:**

- Reinstall Roblox
- Hit "reset all settings" in Roblox Studio's studio settings
- Give Roblox high priority in task manager
- Reboot internet router (even though I'm pretty sure it's not my internet)
- Connect pc to modem directly with ethernet
- disable firewall completely
- factory reset pc

I would be grateful for any help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a fast car it does not mean you can get anywhere in the world in the same amount of time. It depends on many factors such as traffic, road condition, or how far the place is. It is the same for the Internet. When you connect somewhere, you never have a direct connection (unless you threw a fibre to the server). You connect through several intermediate points and your connection quality depends on **each** of them.

Network connection for video streaming is quite different from your average video game. Video streams are based on UDP protocol, which is faster than TCP, that is common in games. Your experience with video streaming is based on whether you can pull data fast enough and the server can give it in the same rate. When you deal with ping, you need that **all** of your packets reach the destination and return to you fast. The bandwidth is not so important here.

To find out why you have the problem would require you to learn about networking quite a lot. But even then you rarely can do something about it except for change ISP maybe. You can begin the investigation by `ping`ing the problem server and a good one over a long time. With that you can find what's happening when you see a spike: either it's a packet loss or just delay. Then you can use `tracert` to find out at which point in route the problem occurs. If it the first step, then the problem is in your router if you use it or ISP otherwise. If it is the last step, then the problem is with the target server. If it is somewhere in the middle then god help you. Even if you change ISP there is no guarantee the problem will be solved. You might try a server in a different region if you can.

The block above is for a fibre connection. If you connect to the internet with a wireless connection then there could be a freaking lot more different issues. Wireless connection is not an option if you want a good ping.

Comment: Thanks for that. The thing is when connecting my pc to my phone's mobile hotspot, the ping problem no longer persists. I also downloaded and tested Roblox on different devices in my home, and found out that the ping also spikes to 1000 for 10 seconds on each of those devices. (Phone and another pc) I have also tested using an ethernet cable to connect the internet modem directly to my pc, but it doesn't matter. Even when getting 500 Mbps download speed, the ping problem persists. Also this problem only happens on one game - Roblox. (The download from Roblox.com and the Microsoft store app.)

Comment: Also, this problem only started happening 5-6 days ago. Roblox was running perfectly fine before that. That's why I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had this problem as well, i can downlod things at 40 MB/s, but have about 999 ping and 35% PL. What i did to fix it is bought a new router.

One thing also is go to the router page (192.168.1.1) sign in, and manage packets and how much data is restricted to application/computer. This also helps.